# Not able to expose std::pair to java bindings properly?

Tags: java, c++, binding, swig

I am using swig to generate bindings for my c++ library in java.

I my native code I have a pair as follows

```
std::pair<std::string,vector <int> >;
```

I want to expose it to java. But when I see my wrap.cxx the are in the form

```
SWIGTYPE_p_Ivectors.
```

And I am not able to get the vector using this swig handle. Eventually I cannot do any vector operations.

I have also included

```
%include <std_vector.i>
```

And also created a template like this

```
%template(Ivectors) vector<int>;
```

Please help me ASAP.

Comment: People giving help in their free time may be put off by demands for help ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one template there. You've already got:

```
%template(Ivectors) vector<int>;
```

You also need:

```
%template(SVpair) std::pair<std::string,vector <int> >;
```